# If clause in haml using variable from mustache

Tags: ruby, haml, mustache

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410996/set-attributes-in-haml-using-variable-in-mustache) question, I want to use if clause in haml file, specifically only display the image when there is actually image url. The code is

```
%div{ :class => "attachment {{ attachment_type }}" }
  %a{ :href => "{{ attachment_url }}", :target=> "_blank"}
    %img.image{ :src => "{{ attachment_pic_url }
```

and I was trying something like:

```
:plain
<%if {{attachment_pic_url}}.present? %>
  <% { %>
    <img class="image" src="{{ attachment_pic_url}}"  %> %>"/>
  <% } %>
```

but it complains 'Unclosed tag'. Any idea of this issue? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `src="{{ attachment_pic_url  %> %>"` ⇒ `src="{{ attachment_pic_url }}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mustache` is logic-less as there are no if statements.

We can use tags instead.

In your case -

```
{{#attachment_pic_url}}
%a{ :href => "{{ attachment_url }}", :target=> "_blank"}
  %img.image{ :src => "{{ attachment_pic_url }}" }
{{/attachment_pic_url}}
```

If the attachment_key_url key does not exist, or exists and has a value of null, undefined, false, 0, or NaN, or is an empty string or an empty list, the block will not be rendered.

Refer https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#false-values-or-empty-lists.

Comment: The closing tag should be {{/attachment_pic_url}} as from the document. It helped to solve the issue. Thanks @Shweta!